# Rest API calling python script before returning answer to client

Tags: python, rest, scripting, server-side

first of all, i apolagise for making such a general question, but it has been really hard to find any useful information on the web.

I would like to create a client side + server side application, which will communicate using a REST api or websockets.

However, my question is the following.
On the server side, after receiving the request from the client,
is it possible to execute a python script, which will return the intended answer, and only then returning that answer to the client?

Let's take an example.

Suppose my client app ask the user which city he is on right now.
Than, the server receives a get request with the name of that city.
Than, the server executes a python script to obtain some information about that city (lets say it searches for the weather).
Only after the script return's the info, can the server return it's answer to the client so it can be rendered.

I hope this is not marked as off topic, as i think this is a relevant general question.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

most serious Python Web frameworks have add-on that will do most of the transport / serialisation job.

Django-REST-Framework and Flask-RESTful are the kings in Python language for full stack REST server side applications.

Otherwise, for simple things and few configuration, you could consider Falcon https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

On client side, use the "requests" package. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: i appreciate your answer, and will look further into django and flask.
However, i would like to ask if you know if that kind of interaction is also possible with a Redux server side implementation. Since Redux is JavaScript, i think it is possible to call scripts and wait for it to answer, is that correct?

Comment: REST is a HTTP based protocol. Clients and servers may be coded in most programming languages on both sides.